# Google Places search implementation

Tags: javascript, openlayers-2, geoext, ext-js, heron-mapping-client

I have a Heron/Geoext/ExtJS map. I found a site with this function and I would like to implement it.

So how can I use this function without their MapCentia.gc2 function? How can I rewrite it to use in my map?

```
     {
            type: "any",
            options: {
                text: '',
                tooltip: 'Search with Google Places',
                iconCls: 'icon-map-magnify',
                id: "googleSearch",
                handler: function (objRef) {
                    if (!searchWin) {
                        searchWin = new Ext.Window({
                            title: "Find",
                            layout: 'fit',
                            width: 300,
                            height: 70,
                            plain: true,
                            closeAction: 'hide',
                            html: '<div style="padding: 5px" id="searchContent"><input style="width: 270px" type="text" id="gAddress" name="gAddress" value="" /></div>',
                            x: 300,
                            y: 70
                        });
                    }
                    if (typeof(objRef) === "object") {
                        searchWin.show(objRef);
                    } else {
                        searchWin.show();
                    }//end if object reference was passed
                    var input = document.getElementById('gAddress');
                    var options = {
                        //bounds: defaultBounds
                        //types: ['establishment']
                    };
                    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
                    //console.log(autocomplete.getBounds());
                    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                        var transformPoint = function (lat, lon, s, d) {
                            var p = [];
                            if (typeof Proj4js === "object") {
                                var source = new Proj4js.Proj(s);    //source coordinates will be in Longitude/Latitude
                                var dest = new Proj4js.Proj(d);
                                p = new Proj4js.Point(lat, lon);
                                Proj4js.transform(source, dest, p);
                            }
                            else {
                                p.x = null;
                                p.y = null;
                            }
                            return p;
                        };
                        var p = transformPoint(place.geometry.location.lng(), place.geometry.location.lat(), "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:900913");
                        var point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(p.x, p.y);
                        MapCentia.gc2.map.setCenter(point, 17);
                        try {
                            placeMarkers.destroy();
                        } catch (e) {
                        }

                        try {
                            placePopup.destroy();
                        } catch (e) {
                        }
// which heron/geoext/extjs is equivalent of these?
                        placeMarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
                        MapCentia.gc2.map.addLayer(placeMarkers);
                        placeMarkers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(point));
                        placePopup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("place", point, null, "<div id='placeResult' style='z-index:1000;width:200px;height:50px;overflow:auto'>" + place.formatted_address + "</div>", null, true, function(){
                            placePopup.destroy();
                            placeMarkers.destroy();
                        });
                        MapCentia.gc2.map.addPopup(placePopup);
                    });

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapCentia.gc2.map is referencing the OpenLayers map object. So just switch it out with Heron.App.map.